# Django Postgres Docker First Migration Failing

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am having some difficulty in setting my app up to be dockerised.
It runs locally without a problem using sqlite. I can delete the sqlite db and run the migrations from scratch and then migrate each of the apps after that.
I can make all the migration files in advance and then delete the sqlite db and run it again from the command line and run manage.py migrate and all tables are created correctly. All good.

However! When I try and dockerise it it all seems to fall apart.

Here is my docker-compose file which creates the postgres container and the django container correctly and I can shell into the django container and connect to the database from the command line using psql and the configured parameters.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - DATABASE_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - DATABASE_NAME=project
      - DATABASE_USER=project
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - PORT=8000
      - DEBUG=False
    #command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    command: ping google.com
    networks:
      - project-network
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=project
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - project-network
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready --username=project && psql --username=project --list"
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 20
networks:
  project-network:
    name: project_network
```

I have treble checked the environment variables. All fine.
I have run manage.py shell and run tests from there using django imports. All connects fine.

You will note I just have the Django container set up to ping google for now. This just keeps the container alive so I can shell into it and check things.

This is the error I get when running manage.py migrate

```
oot@37cd4045690a:/home/app/webapp# python3 manage.py makemigrations core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "projects_environment_type_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_type_category"."environment_type_category" FROM "projects_...
```

This is with no migration files created. All migration folders in all apps are empty. I was just trying to go back to basics and create the basic django setup and first schema.

Here is my requirements.txt

```
django==4.1.1
django-crispy-forms
crispy-bulma
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-seed
django-environ
psycopg2==2.9.6
```

I cannot figure out why I cannot even configure a basic django setup using postgres. Why does it work with sqlite (even in docker) and not with postgres?

From the docs

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes][1]

My settings file database section looks like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': env('DATABASE_ENGINE'),
        #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'NAME': env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': env('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('DATABASE_PORT')
    }
}
```

The environment vars in docker-compose are :

```
environment:
      - DATABASE_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - DATABASE_NAME=project
      - DATABASE_USER=project
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I have figured out that when running Django against a blank sqlite database the migrations work fine, but not so with Postgres. I have to disconnect all the applications from the settings and url configs, run the initial migration, then reconnect the applications and respective urls and then makemigrations and migrate from there. I am trying to figure out how to do this nicely from a CI/CD pipeline :-/